# how to install the regular updates

Tags: updates

I need help. I installed it without using the internet to install updates while it was installing. it had no errors after install. I now cannot find the update button to check for updates. Can someone help me either to find it or tell me what to type into the command line in order to install the system updates.

Answer (score 3):

You can install the updates through two methods: using a graphical software, or command line.

## Graphical Method

Using the Software Updater. Open the Dash and search for "updater". Open it, and continue with the instructions.

[image]

## Command-line Method

Open a terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and type in the following commands separately:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The first command only "updates" the package list and doesn't install anything. The second command installs packages that need to be upgraded.

Comment: Can these commands work when I press Ctrl + Alt+ F1?

Comment: Yes, of course.